# how to solve The method add(double, double, int, double) in the type main is not applicable for the arguments (double, double, double, double)

Tags: java

if you are replying pls show me code and tips
the code comes from bro code and im still learnin sorry

i have fixed a couple of other errors but it still doesn't work

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = add(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0);
        System.out.println(x);
    }   
            
    static int add (int a , int b) {
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #1");
        return a + b;
    }
        
    static int add (int a , int b, int c) {
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #2");
        return a + b + c;
    }
    
    static int add (int a , int b, int c, int d) {
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #3");
        return a + b + c + d;
    }
        
    static int add (double a , double b) {
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #4");
        return a + b;
    }

    static int add (double a ,double b, double c){
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #5");
        return a + b + c;
    }

    static int add (double a , double b, int c, double d) {
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #6");
        return a + b + c + d;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXUAQ.png)

Comment: You're trying to call a method with 4 `double` arguments. You don't have such method: hence - compilation error.

Comment: The 3rd parameter should be an `int` but you are passing a `double`.

Comment: Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp The image is perfectly fine in this case. The full code is uploaded as text. Images are bad on their own, but if they're supplementary there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Michael Seems useless to me. The code is cut-off as is the error message. OP wasted their time grabbing a screen shot and uploading it. And they wasted our time by having us click on the link and visit and external site for some pointless image.

Comment: Another issue: The last three functions should probably return `double` not `int`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It's not massively helpful, but I see no reason to actively discourage them from doing it. Sometimes the IDE will show something that those trying to repro with the same code won't see, if for example the IDE is misconfigured. Almost all of the reasons in that post you linked to only apply when the image is posted *instead* of the text, not *in addition to* it, so I think it's only going to confuse them. As for the site being external, imgur is what Stack Overflow chooses to host its images, so they can do nothing about that.

Comment: @Michael Agree to disagree, but this is not the place to discuss it. That would be Meta, I guess. Which, btw, is where I got that link: from [the SO Faq on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm familiar with meta... That doesn't mean that the reasons on that page apply to this situation. There are 15 reasons given in that first answer, and none of them apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the errors, you need to do a few things:

1. In methods 4, 5, and 6 - update the "return type" from `int` to `double` (the one which goes after the word `static`)
2. In method 6 - update the parameter `int c` to `double c`

So your methods 4, 5, and 6 should look like this:

```
    static double add(double a, double b) {
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #4");
        return a + b;
    }

    static double add(double a, double b, double c){
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #5");
        return a + b + c;
    }

    static double add(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
        System.out.println("this is a overloaded method #6");
        return a + b + c + d;
    }
```